# Как длина ячейке в базе данных влияет на производительность?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как влияет размер ячейки, например типа `VARCHAR` на производительность. Если в поле VARCHAR(255) записать слово "`Test`", то эти данные будут занимать 1+4 байта, но не 255, что есть хорошо( в отличии от CHAR). Что если на некоторые поля ставить максимальное значение varchar(65535)? Это как-то повлияет на скорость работы большой базы? Вопрос возник из-за того, что клиент вставляя текст через визуальные редакторы превысил лимит и соответственно текст обрезался. Обычно он вставлял посты до 100 символов, но в этот раз все было иначе...

Comment: *Что если на некоторые поля ставить максимальное значение varchar(65535)?* Увеличится расход дискового пространства. Несильно. По скорости работы - вряд ли удастся детектировать разницу. Всё это -  при тех же размерах данных. Конечно, если юзеры начнут запихивать в эти поля поэмы, и расход диска, и трафик, и производительность начнут отличаться...

Comment: @Akina, "Увеличится расход дискового пространства" а каким образом, ведь данных будет столько напишет. Я к чему. Представим такое, что я поставил поле с длиной 255, но по факту используется постоянно 10-15 и может 1-2 записи из 100 занимают 200-255

Comment: .FRM-файл гарантированно больше. PS. А ещё - не факт что тебе удастся сделать размер равным 65535... зависит от движка и кодировки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказано, конкретные детали зависят от движка, но вот некоторые общие вехи и некоторые применительно к InnoDB:

- Если максимальная длина значения **может** превышать 255 **байт** (`VARCHAR(256+)` для latin1, `VARCHAR(86+)` для utf8) — в поле размера будет 2 байта вместо одного. [1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)
- Для InnoDB, размер **значения** больше ≥768 **байт** — часть значения будет хранится отдельно (off-page), вероятно падение производительности. [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html)

При приближении к лимитам в дело вступают другие силы:

- Для InnoDB, если размер всей записи больше страницы (16k), то самое длинное(ые) поле будет хранится отдельно. [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html)
- Если кодировка не однобайтовая, а максимально возможный размер записи больше, чем 64k, то самая длинное(ые) поле(я) будут преобразовано в `TEXT` при создании таблицы.
- Максимальный размер всей записи, включая все служебные поля не должен превышать 64k. [3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html)

т.о. `VARCHAR(65535)` — в принципе не возможно создать, для больших кодировок он по факту будет текстом, а для latin1 это просто не удастся, с другой стороны, при вменяемых размерах остальных полей таблицы, скажем `VARCHAR(16384)` никак не должен сказаться на производительности, покуда в него не начать засовывать значения длиннее 767-ми байт. Ограничение на `VARCHAR` на 1-2 порядка меньше максимального — это ИМХО больше защита от ошибок, нежели значение влияющее на производительность/реализацию.

Comment: cпасибо за ответ. А скажите, если допустим 2-3 значения из 100 превышают 767 байтов, то вопрос падении производительности касается всей таблицы или только при работе с данной записью.

Comment: только с данными записями